# PyQt connector run twice

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I'm trying to run this using NodeGraphQt library.
value_changed signal would run twice.
An example would be, if initial my inputs are 20/25, which means input_counts is 5, then if condition is met. The code would go ahead and create 5 inputs. but then the signal is emitted again, which would force it to run through elif condition this time (all elif conditions are now met since existing_inputs now becomes 5) and sending out errors because the inputs already exist.

```
 def __init__(self):
        super(RelayIONode, self).__init__()

        self.add_text_input('Inputs', 'IN: Start/End Values', "##/##", tab='Widget')

        self.get_widget('Inputs').value_changed.connect(self.on_input_changed)


    def on_input_changed(self, name, value):
        io_series = self.get_widget('IOSeries').get_value()

        existing_inputs = len(self.inputs())

        # Disconnect value_changed signal temporarily
        # self.get_widget('Inputs').value_changed.disconnect(self.on_input_changed)

        # Split the input value at '/' to get the input series and counts
        try:
            input_start, input_end = value.split('/')
            input_start = int(input_start)
            input_end = int(input_end)
            input_counts = input_end - input_start + 1
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: End value must be greater than Start value")
            # Reconnect the value_changed signal after displaying the error message
            self.get_widget('Inputs').value_changed.connect(self.on_input_changed)
            return


        if input_counts > existing_inputs == 0:
            # Add inputs
            for i in range(existing_inputs, input_counts):
                try:
                    self.add_input(f'{io_series}{str(i + input_start).zfill(2)}', multi_input=True)
                except:
                    print("Error adding input 1")

        elif 0 < existing_inputs < input_start:
            # Add inputs
            for i in range(input_counts):
                try:
                    self.add_input(f'{io_series}{str(i + input_start).zfill(2)}', multi_input=True)
                except:
                    print("Error adding input 2")
                    print(input_start, input_end, existing_inputs)

        # Reconnect value_changed signal
        # self.get_widget('Inputs').value_changed.connect(self.on_input_changed)
        return
```

I tried to disconnect then reconnect with similar results.
I would like for the function to only run once per value change...

Comment: Disconnecting and reconnecting like this within the same function call is pointless. You should at least keep track of the *previous* input count and eventually react to the new changes. I'm not familiar with that library, but providing a proper context and a valid [mre] would certainly help.